# Extract values from template literal types

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have types like this:

```js
type SegmentBase = string;
type ParamSegment = `:${string}`;
type Segment = SegmentBase | ParamSegment;

type Path = `${Segment}/${Segment}`;
```

Is it now possible to construct a type `Extractor<T extends Path>` that extracts the `${string}` part of a `ParamSegment` in the following way:

```js
Extractor<'foo/:bar'>
// turns into
{
    bar: string;
}
```

```js
Extractor<':foo/:bar'>
// turns into
{
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}
```

```js
Extractor<'foo/bar'>
// turns into
{}
```

Comment: My mistake, should have been a different type. Will edit to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a recursive auxiliary type for this.

First, create a type that matches the parameter names

```js
type _UnwrapParam<P extends string, S extends string[]> = P extends `:${infer Q}` ? [Q, ...S] : S;

type _Match<T extends string, S extends string[]> = T extends `${infer P}/${infer R}`
  ? [...UnwrapParam<P, S>, ..._Match<R, S>]
  : _UnwrapParam<T, S>

export type Match<T extends string> = _Match<T, []>[number];
```

Then you can do

```js
export type Extractor<T extends string> = {
  [K in Match<T>]: string;
};
```

**Edit:** Since Typescript 4.5, it's better to implement the `_Match` type as bellow, so it can benefit from [Tail recursion elimination](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types).

```js
type _Match<
  T extends string,
  S extends string[]
> = T extends `${infer P}/${infer R}`
  ? _Match<R, _UnwrapParam<P, S>>
  : _UnwrapParam<T, S>;
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you need something like this:

```
type Extractor<S extends string> = 
  S extends `${infer L}/${infer R}`
    ? {
      [K in L | R as K extends `:${infer Key}` ? Key : never]: string
    }
    : never
```

Some test cases:

```
type T1 = Extractor<'foo/:bar'>
// type T1 = {
//     bar: string;
// }

type T2 = Extractor<':foo/:bar'>
// type T2 = {
//     foo: string;
//     bar: string;
// }

type T3 = Extractor<'foo/bar'>
// type T3 = {}
```

Please add more test cases, if this does not fit your use case.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhDmBbCA7YAhAhgZ2gXim2ACcBLFeAbgChRIoAFTYzROJVYKAgAwC4AJAG8iZCgF8eNOtHbI03WAnkYc0AD6NmrOZxq1w0AKIAPEpgDGwAPbEAPDCgQzqACbZCJcvAB8i6lCwTi4o7lA8wuQAZhDEUAAy4gD0kSgxcQBKkgGBUAD8UEI5uVAA2gDSUOQJUJoZUDhQlc7Abh78qelNECCS%20d0gUHxQKBAAbrEAusOi3sVQ4vPDoxPE1Ab0ACoAjIqm5la2dgDkUdbWSXwARszHPusyUJsATHtmLIf2x3xnF9e39w20E2AGY3gcbF9fkkbsQ7tQgA)